# How do I change a hash using new hash values?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have these hashes:

```
{"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "k" => 14}
{"b" => 51, "c" => 2, "d"  => 8}
```

I need to write code, so that after manipulation, the result would be:

```
{"a" => 1, "b" => 51, "c" => 2, "k" => 14}
```

I tried:

```
h1.each do |h, j|
  h2.each do |hh, jj|
    if h == hh
      j = jj
    end
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work. Also I think this is ugly code, so how would could it be written better/right?

I though I should compare the two hashes, and, if the second key is the same as the first, change the first hash value to the second hash's value.

Comment: Are you leaving out keys in the second hash that are not in the first (i.e., is `"d"` not added because it's not in the first)?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard yes, but would be great if you post with adding d too...

Comment: @CarySwoveland and what? Is that reason for downvote? You are not so good in russian, as i in english... that's all

Comment: I rarely downvote and certainly would never do so for incorrect grammar.  Many people whose first language is English incorrectly  insert an apostrophe in the plural (as opposed to possessive) form of a word.  My comment (which I see has been removed) was intended to be educational, not critical, and mildly humorous (though I see you're not laughing).  You certainly are correct that your English is better than my Russian.  I feel extremely fortunate that the world choose mine as its universal language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the entries in `h2` and update the corresponding entry in `h1` only if it already exists:

```ruby
h2.each { |k,v| h1[k]=v if h1.include?(k) }
h1 # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>51, "c"=>2, "k"=>14 }
```

Also, if you want to update the entries as above and *also add new entries from `h2`* you can simply use the [`Hash#merge!` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21):

```
h1.merge!(h2)
h1 # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>51, "c"=>2, "k"=>14, "d"=>8}
```

Comment: h1.include?(k) but will this no work, if i have for example in second att but in first is att_1,

Comment: @brabertaser1992: correct, if any key is in `h2` but *not* in `h1`, per your example, it will not be added to `h1`.

Comment: ok, just was confused, that include search all entries... but not exactly

Comment: That should probably be the `Hash#merge!` method, since the OP seems to want to mutate the existing hash.

Comment: ..or `if h1[k]`, but I prefer what you have.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: yes, I considered that form but it will fail if `h1[k]` is `false` or `nil`.